# Doctrine ORM - join not related entity as subobject of main entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I'm working on Symfony 3.3.6 and get some trouble with joins.

I have two entities:

1. ShippingOrder
2. Client

ShippingOrder has fields `giver` and `payer` that means who wants to proceed that order and who'll pay for this.

My select query looks:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('o, giver, payer')
        ->from('ClientBundle:Shipping\ShippingOrder', 'o')
        ->join('ClientBundle:Client', 'giver', 'WITH', 'o.shipGiver = giver.id')
        ->addSelect('giver')
        ->join('ClientBundle:Client', 'payer', 'WITH', 'payer.id = o.shipPayer')
        ->addSelect('payer')
        ->orderBy('o.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
$result = $qb->getResult();
```

And when i loop in view returned result, single query result has three objects, not one with related subentities. What can I do to prevent this, and keep each iterate as one object?

Here what it looks like when loop only one entity:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pTWY.png)

I want to get all that red as one entity, and all that yellow as second.